# Switching tabs in VS Code causes Angular to do a hot-reload

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

When I switch tabs or open a new doc in VS Code, my Angular ng serve hot reloads.  I would like it to only reload when I save a document.  `Auto Save` is turned off in VS Code.  Angular is being served by running `ng serve` in Windows Terminal.  I am running VS Code 1.49 and Angular CLI 9.1.6.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this was related to Git in VS Code.  When I disable Git the problem goes away:

```
C:\Users\-----\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json

"git.enabled": false,
"git.path": null,
"git.autofetch": false
```